# Is it a good practice to mark setters private in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

[HibernateDocs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/persistent-classes.html)
In this link to hibernate docs, in the example, in `Cat.class` the `setId()` is declared `private`.
Is it a good practice to mark `setters` private for the fields whose values I do not want to change?

Also can this be used as an alternative to marking fields `final`? Providing default constructor and constructor with desired fields and making setters private for those fields.

I want this answer in Hibernate's context, not java's abstraction.
**Is this a good practice and should it be used?**

Comment: "Is it a good practice to mark setters private for the fields whose values I do not want to change." - Are you telling or asking?

Comment: @Jose Gomez Asking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think no. Fields Encapsulation methods are used to access/set private fields from the outside of a class. If you don't want to modify your field you should declare it final or you should not declare a setter method. The hibernate example shown is an exception. If you persist an Entity the id property (if autogenerated) is setted automatically by reflection. Making this setter private is a good way to preserve this value without the risk to manually modify it in your code

Comment: I agree.. But because of Hibernate I'm forced to declare the setter `methods`

Comment: yes you have to declare it but you could make it private for the reasons above.Expecially for the id property. You are forced to make encapsulation for an hibernate entity but you can avoid modifying properties that you don't want to modify by using private accessor.

Comment: So is it acceptable if i mark it as private? I mean by the Industry standards and all

Comment: Yes, It is acceptable. I always use private setter for the ID property